Which interaction is more user friendly to filter a list of customers by first letter on mobile?
I'm designing filters to help users find out what they need in a very long list of customers (more than 5000 entries on average). One of the options is to filter by Last Name or First Name's initial letter (i.e. the list would only show entries which have J as the customer's last name's initial letter).
How do you think it would be the best interaction on small screen devices: having all letters displayed at the same time with a horizontal scroll to go through them all or by grouping letters?


The second option would behave like this: instead of displaying each letter individually, the user would see fewer options with labels like: "A-G", "H-N", etc. By tapping one chip the user would see all letters within the selected range. i.e. A, B, C, D, E, F and G.

The latter would be beneficial since every letter would be only two taps away: one tap to reveal the individual letters of the selected group and another tap to select the letter. While the first option would make the user tap a few times to scroll until they reach the last letters of the alphabet.
The UI elements and components can fit up to 7 individual letters on the viewport.
This is my first question here. I'm very excited to learn from you!
Thanks! :)

The “best” solution is very subjective without more details. Now it reads like a review request. Can you edit the question to define the problem with the current designs from the perspective of users and usage context?

I'll add this as a comment since it doesn't answer your question directly: the expected UI element for this type of filters is a predictive search or a dropdown. Your solution looks  nice, but it requires more interactions and it also doesn't allow for fuzzy searches

An alternative is to use something like a Show More button to show/hide the full alphabet button panel:


I wonder if having a regular grid is better instead of this offset grid. As it is the offset grid kind of looks like a keyboard layout but the letters are in alphabetical order, not qwerty order.

Apparently it is a mobile interface, remember that each key will be pressed by a finger, the shifted grid gives a better option to not press the wrong key.

On mobile devices, horizontal scrolling is quite common, so I would choose the first version, since it has a few advantages:

selection and deselection require only one tap instead of many (going back and forth between groups)
selecting multiple letters can be done directly, without having to switch groups
scrolling and identifying letters require less mental effort than remembering the alphabet order

Displaying all letters at once on multiple lines, or having a "show more" button (like @Danielillo suggested) might work even better, since the user can see all the selected letters. This assumes that you have enough vertical space. Don't forget that letter buttons must to have a certain minimum size for good accessibility.
Also, regarding your mockup, there are a few things you need to consider:

Since you have multiple filters, it might be better to rename the page title as "Filters".
It's useful to have a header for each filter, to reduce cognitive effort for your users.
For complex interfaces like the letter filter, it's better to add explanations like "as first letter for".

I made this basic wireframe as example:

